# Cargo profile overrides for std lib and external crates

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In *release* mode we can add [debug](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#debug) info via this:

```
[profile.release]
debug = 1
```

That adds debug info, such as file and line number to all the code, at the cost of a bigger binary size. I want debug info to only be added for the application's code, not the std lib or external crates, as that should reduce the "bloat" in the compiled binary dramatically.

I read [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides) we can override Cargo profile settings. So I imagine we should add something like this:

```
[profile.release.package."*"]
debug = 0
```

The above doesn't work (i.e. line numbers are still present for std-lib functions in the stack trace), so I guess I just need to specify something else as a [Package ID](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/pkgid-spec.html). How can I exclude both external crates and the std lib?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? Does it not decrease the size? Does it remove all the debug information, instead of only for dependencies? I've tried it, and at least those two points work fine for me.

Comment: @Caesar The setting doesn't seem to disable the debug info for std lib.

Answer (score 1):

The debug information is generated at compile-time and the std lib is not recompiled when building a crate normally. Try:

```
cargo build -Zbuild-std --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --release
```

(With target adjusted to whatever you're currently on.) This requires nightly.